# MVC5 Facebook Login Broken for Mobile Devices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-5, facebook-login

I've implemented the Facebook login integration into a website I'm creating. It works fine on my desktop but some test users have errors logging in from their mobile device. Here is my issue:

It stems from the ExternalLoginCallback Action in the Account controller.

This is part of what mine looks like.

```
     public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
     {
            var result = await AuthenticationManager.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            if (result == null || result.Identity == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", new { mode = "firstError" });
            }

            var idClaim = result.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            if (idClaim == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", new { mode = "secondError" });
            }
     }
```

For some reason when mobile devices login the first condition fails and gets sent to the login page. I've added a dummy parameter so that I could test on the mobile device.

Any ideas as to why this code would behave differently?

Comment: Same exact problem for me.

Comment: @JustinSkiles see solution below :)

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to update this before but after some research I confirmed that this is a bug. I forget all the details but I'm just referencing some code to help everyone else with this.

See the Session workaround to "wake" things up.

```
        public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
        {
            Session["Workaround"] = 0;
            // Request a redirect to the external login provider
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            Session["Workaround"] = 0;
```

This should fix the issue.